# How can I get my AJAX button press request to work in my Django environment?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, button

So basically I want to use a JS string variable in a python function, and then return it back to a JS variable. I assume the best way to do this is through Json/ajax?

To start, I have a html element where a string is placed in it.

```
<h2 id="output"></h2>
```

My plan is to pull that value from the HTML (shown in the AJAX statement below):

```
var word = $("#output").val();
```

and use AJAX to send it to the backend for a python script that checks whether or not the word is a real English word (returning true/false).

With the AJAX code I have, I keep getting returned an undefined variable.

**Here is the AJAX code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit_word').click(function() {
      var word = $("#output").val();
      $.ajax({
          url: '{% url 'wordgame' %}', //not sure
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {word:word, csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",},
          success: function(response) {
              var word_result = JSON.parse(response.result);
              console.log(response.result);
              $("#check-word").text(word_result);
          },
          error: function(response) {
              console.log(response.result);
          }
      });
  });
});
```

**As well as my views function:**

```
def fetch_word(request):
    word = request.POST.get('word')
    result = check_if_word_in_dictionary(word)
    return JsonResponse({'result': result})
```

Whenever I click the button, it executes the 'error' part of my ajax statement:

```
error: function(response) {
              console.log(response.result);
          }
```

Which prints 'undefined' in the console. I'm completely new to ajax/django so I assume it's just going to be a Syntax error, but I've spent way too much time trying to figurer this out :(

Comment: `.val` is for getting the current (possibly user-entered) value of a *form input*. You probably want `.text()` here if you must use jQuery.

Comment: Alright so that fixed the string and I used console.log(word) to confirm that. It's still being pushed to 'error' so I'm curious if i'm not understanding the 'url:' part correctly (it is giving me ""POST /wordgame/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11574" so I don't think it's failing there.

Comment: Sorry, I only just read the last part of your question. It's been quite a while since I used jQuery but I don't know why you expect the error returned to have a `result` property. Try just logging the whole thing (which you call `response`), surely something in there will tell you what the actual error is.

Comment: I’ll keep messing around with it. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

change the word response to data in function parameters and try again. that is because there is no response in jquery, it is data https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

example

```
$.ajax({
      url: '{% url 'wordgame' %}', //not sure
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {word:word, csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",},
      success: function(data) {
          var word_result = data);
          console.log(data.result);
          $("#check-word").text(word_result);
      },
      error: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
      }
```

Comment: this helped as well as the other fix from 'val()' to 'text()' however it's still being pushed to 'error'. Maybe I'm not directing to my views/url files correctly? I have a feeling it could be that but I'm really new to all of this and don't fully understand how urls actually work

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I was getting a 500 error. I was unaware about Django’s debugging feature that I can use and it helped walk me through the error I was getting! Everything is working properly now.  Most of the issue stemmed from my views.py and urls.py connection plus some syntax errors  in the views function